# the script gives error "The parameter app_id is required" in facebook login even when passed in the code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login

i have developed a website in which i want to incorporate "login with facebook" button. i have coded the necessary part and also made the facebook application for it..in my code i have even passed the app id and secret key. Even after doing so when i press the button to login via facebook it gives me an error "The parameter app_id is required" . this is my login script

```
    <?php 
            include 'fbaccess.php'
            if(empty($user))
            {
            ?>
            <form name="fblogin" action="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">
            <input type="submit" name="fbsubmit" value="Login with Facebook"/>
            </form>
            <?php                   
            } 
            else {
                echo $user_info;
            }
            ?>
```

and this is my fbaccess.php code

```
    <?php
     $app_id        = APP_ID;
     $app_secret    = APP_SECRET;
     $site_url  = "www.jajabora.com/index.php";

     include_once "src/facebook.php";

     //creating the object of facebook from the API
     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'        => $app_id,
 'secret'   => $app_secret,
  ));

      //getting the user id to check whether the user is logged in or not
       $user = $facebook->getUser();

      //if user is not authenticated api/me will throw an exception, hence we will know                he isnt logged in after logging out
      /*checks if the user is logged in or not*/if($user){
      // Single query method 
  try{
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   }/*if exception the user has logged out after logging in hence not authenticated*/
  catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
    $user = NULL;
  }
      // Single query method ends 
      }
       if($user){
  // Get logout URL
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
      }else{
  // Get login URL
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream, user_birthday,user_location,email,first_name,last_name,gender',
    ));
       }
      if($user){
  // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who has a valid session.

      //========= Batch requests over the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK ========
  // Save your method calls into an array
  $queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user)/*,
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/home?limit=50'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),*/
    );

   // POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
   try{
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
     }catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
      }

    //Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in   ['body'] as a JSON
   //string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
    $user_info      = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
    $feed           = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
    /*$friends_list     = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
    $photos         = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);*/
        //========= Batch requests over the Facebook Graph API using the PHP-SDK ends =====

       try {
   $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
    'message'       => 'Check out jajabora.com',
    'link'          => 'http://jajabora.com'/*,
    'picture'       => 'http://25labs.com/images/25-labs-160-160.jpg'*/,
    'name'          => 'Jajabora',
    'caption'       => 'jajabora.com',
    'description'       => 'A carpooling website. highly recommended to  save fuel and cost of travel',
    ));
           }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
         error_log($e);
               }
                }
              ?>
```

Please guide me. i am a newbie in facebook login coding

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that problem might be hiding here:

```
<form name="fblogin" action="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">
        <input type="submit" name="fbsubmit" value="Login with Facebook"/>
</form>
```

You are sending get request to the generated link, why? User is supposed to follow that link and give your application permissions, try something like this instead of the form:

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl?>">Login with Facebook </a>
```

In order to redirect user to certain page, add redirect_uri to getLoginUrl:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'publish_stream, user_birthday,user_location,email,first_name,last_name,gender',
redirect_uri => PAGE_URL
));
```

Make sure that this page belongs to the domain your set up in app settings.

Comment: your solution gives this error - The redirect_uri URL must be absolute. also let me know that does the app require to be reviewed by people from facebook before it starts working ?

Comment: No, noone reviews your app. If redirect_uri is wrong, you should look into app setting on facebook, or add "redirect_url" parameter in your getLoginUrl (after scope), with full url to your page)

Comment: actually i m not sure where to put what code...on the login page i have a button which redirects to the loginUrl which is set to mysite URL. now i dont know which url to assign to mysiteurl. also which url to assign in the app? the one of the login page or the one after succesful login

Comment: Well, that's up to you. You know the workflow of your page, so you should try and see which option works best for you

Comment: is there a problem regarding "oauth" ? because i havent included it in my code

Comment: oauth authorization is what user goes through when giving your app permission to use his data, which will result in your app getting certain access token to work with that user's data.

Comment: yeah thats right that i know the work flow of my page...but i dont know which URL to put where..this is what i wanna do..on login (x.php) i want a "login with facebook"..onclicking it should take me to y.php after the user accepts all the condition..now tell me where should i put what ?

Comment: Edited post, your "y.php" should be in PAGE_URL

Comment: thats how it is..it still gives me the same error - The redirect_uri URL must be absolute ... this is how i have given the site url(assuming by page url u mean site url)=www.websitename.com/y.php ... please help me..i am really on the verge of breakdown

Comment: phew, atlast some break through...thanks alot..u dont know what favor u have done..highly grateful.now we have reached to a new problem. i m not able to publish a status (the last code in the fbaccess.php file). it is generating an exception "Array"

Comment: every error solved..i m grateful to u...now please can you tell me what to do when the user presses log out on my website?

Comment: when i logout it takes me to my facebook home page and also the app is not publishing anything as user's status even though its programmed to do so...what to do ?

Comment: Pretty sure you can make redirect url for logging out as well. As for Posting status, that's different question, so i suggest you create new one with all the information regarding it.